# how much time it will take to charge a 48v 35amphr battery using a solar panel of 20w

Tags: solar-cell, lead-acid

please help me out with this problem.I have tried several sites , but i didnt get a specipic method.please kindly include formulas used also.

Comment: A simple approach is the battery can deliver 1680W for an hour so divide by 20 and it'll take 84 hours at full sunlight with 100% efficiency in every part. The problem can get pretty complex in reality though because sunlight isn't constant and you need to account for conversion efficiences at different voltages. Also the temperature / age of the panel and batteries can also come into play.

Comment: "Essentially, all models are wrong, some models are useful" - George Box. ALL the models provided are certainly wrong. Usefulness is TBD. Unless a "panel to battery"  matching controller aka MPPT controller is provided, systems **USUALLY** severely mismatch the panel and battery and you get about 50%-66% of possible output. ie a 12V system usually has an 18V optimum voltage out panel (really!!!) so an 48V system would have a 72V panel when optimally rated. Loading this with a 48V ~~~ battery makes it~~ a current source. Icc ~= Wpanel/Vpanel = 20W/72V = ~=280 mA....

Answer (score 2):

Battery chemistry unknown - assume lead acid.

Site location unknown and crucial. Assume 2h/day of equivalent full sun in mid winter.
See http://www.gaisma.com for your site.
Use lowest monthly value from kWh/m^2/day chart as average sunshine hours/day.

There is no rocket science in working this out BUT there is much more to it than most people realise.

- "Essentially, all models are wrong, some models are useful" - George Box.

ALL the models provided in other answers so far are certainly wrong.
Usefulness is TBD.
Unless a "panel to battery" matching controller aka MPPT controller is provided, systems USUALLY severely mismatch the panel and battery and you get about 50%-66% of possible output.
ie a 12V system usually has an 18V optimum voltage out panel (really!!!) (look at the specs for some real panels).
So an 48V system would have a 72V panel when optimally rated.
Loading this with a 48V ~~~ battery makes it~~ a current source.
Icc = constant current into battery in full sun.

I_short_circuit > Icc > I_max_power

If the panel maker quotes Imp (I at maximum power) and Isc (I at short circuit) - both applying in full sunlight, then.

Icc ~~~~= (Imp + Isc) /2

Commonly you are quoted Wmp (power out at optimum load) and Vmp ( Vout at optimum load).
If so

Icc ~= Wpanel/Vpanel = 20W/72V = ~=280 mA....

You can use a < 18V Vmp panel with a 12V lead acid battery BUT this value has been chosen by industry to ensure that the battery can be properly charged under all conditions. In a 48V system 72V is definitely excessive but you'd be unsafe to get Vmp too close to V_battery_nominal.

---

So at 100% efficiency charge time would be about 35AH/0.28A = 125 hours.

IF Joe's claims were applicable you may need to double this.
HOWEVER you are charging at 1/120th of C = C/120 and I wot that efficiency will be approximately awesome across most of the range IF your battery is lead acid.
If it's LiFePO4 they WILL be awesome.

I'd guesstimate 90%+ so t_charge would be maybe 125 hours /90% =~ 140 hours.
This is closish to Joe's 168h BUT for different reasons.

Shaktal's answer is too low due to assuming the panel can deliver 20W when, as above, it usually cannot.

Joe's translation into days using 8 hours/day of sun is also very optimistic (alas.)   Panels give rated power when optimally loaded and in full sun of about 1000 W/m^2/day.

The equivalent hours of full sun vary widely with site and season and are 6+ hours at the very best sites in mid summer (just over 7h/day in Kabul in mid summer - hopefully you are not doing an installation there) - and often ~= 2 hrs equivalent/day in many US locations in mid Winter. In northern US eg NYNY it can be worse and in more northern realms (Canada, Netherlands on north etc) it can be under an hour a day equivalent.
Moscow Russia is about 20 minutes full sun equivalent/day in mid winter on average - no great surprise.

SO you need to say where you are wanting to use this panel and whether you want the answer to apply in mid winter.

More information will help get you better answers.

---

### ADDED

The [1996 Sandia labs paper cited by Joe](http://windandsunpower.com/Download/Lead%20Acid%20Battery%20Efficiency.pdf) -
"A Study of Lead-Acid Battery Efficiency Near Top-of-Charge and the Impact on PV System Design"

Here is a 2010 [ruder than needed, and probably also wrong, complete dismissalof its results](http://www.solarpaneltalk.com/showthread.php?7058-A-Study-of-Lead-Acid-Battery-Efficiency-Near-Top-of-Charge)

This is extremely valuable. Interestingly, he gets 62% (PV solar energy in)/(energy out of controller) using a load optimising MPPT controller. My 'rule of thumb' is 50% overall for a non-MPPT system which is a reasonably close fit to what he gets. He also explains how his system could be better.
[Extremely good 2012 in depth informed well written analysis of overall long term efficincy of solar PV systems](http://www.resilience.org/stories/2012-09-19/blow-blow-pv-system-efficiency-case-study-storage)

[Useful - 2005 - Lifetime modelling of Lead Acid batteries](http://orbit.dtu.dk/fedora/objects/orbit:88309/datastreams/file_7710966/content)

[Useful discussion about development of batteries for solar systems](http://mnre.gov.in/file-manager/UserFiles/report_batteries_solar_photovoltaic_applications.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

We have the formula for electrical power:

$$P=I^{2}R=IV$$

And by the definition of power:

$$P=\frac{\mathrm{d}W}{\mathrm{d}t}\implies W = \int_{0}^{t}P\:\mathrm{d}t'=Pt$$

We therefore have for \$V=48 \text{V}\$, \$It=35 \text{Ah}\$:

$$Pt=VIt=48\times35=1680\text{Wh}$$

Dividing this by the power delivered by the solar panel:

$$t=\frac{1680\text{Wh}}{20\text{W}}=84\text{h}$$

So it will take approximately \$84\$ hours to charge the battery assuming a constant power delivered by the solar panel of \$20\text{W}\$. In practice it will take longer to charge due to varying sun exposure throughout the day and night.

Comment: I think the only thing you can say from this simple analysis is that it will take __at least__ 84 hours, not _approximately_ 84 hours. Due to inefficiencies in the electronics and in the electrochemical process I expect the real number is closer to twice your estimate.